# How can print an image from image data JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, printing

I want print an image by PDF, I have a button print:

```
<input type="button" onclick="PrintImage()" value="Print">
```

And I want print to window like below:

```
function PrintImage(){
   var myImage = "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAABOkAAAKIC.........";
    window.open( myImage );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the solution i got for your question.. :D 
This may help you ..

```
    <input type="button" onclick="PrintImage()" value="Print">
<script>
function PrintImage(){
   var myImage = "data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhEAAQAMQAAORHHOVSKudfOulrSOp3WOyDZu6QdvCchPGolfO0o/XBs/fNwfjZ0frl3/zy7////wAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACH5BAkAABAALAAAAAAQABAAAAVVICSOZGlCQAosJ6mu7fiyZeKqNKToQGDsM8hBADgUXoGAiqhSvp5QAnQKGIgUhwFUYLCVDFCrKUE1lBavAViFIDlTImbKC5Gm2hB0SlBCBMQiB0UjIQA7";
    //var image = new Image();
    //image.src=myImage;
    var myWindow = window.open("", "Image");
    myWindow.document.write('<img src="'+myImage+'"/>');
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, but result is: [object HTMLImageElement]

Comment: You should append the image element.
myWindow.document.appendChild(image)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<input type="button" onclick="PrintImage()" value="Print">

<script type="text/javascript">
function PrintImage() {
    var myImage = "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAABOkAAAKIC.........";
    var myWindow = window.open("", "Image");
    myWindow.document.write("<img src='"+myImage+"''>");
    myWindow.print();
}
</script>
```